How do I use git clone from within a Colab docker container?
I recently followed the instructions at this link to host a "local runtime" of Colab on a remote VM equipped with a NVIDIA A100 (80 GB).
I ssh into VM, run the docker using this command:
docker run --gpus=all -p 127.0.0.1:9000:8080 us-docker.pkg.dev/colab-images/public/runtime
and head to Colab on my local machine to start a session with a local runtime. I use the link I get from the remote VM to start it. Everything works a treat (I can see the details of the VM, RAM, Disk space, VRAM etc are all correct).
However, if I try to use "!git clone" the execution eventually stops with an error of this kind:
/# git clone https://github.com/fmenol/dare-rare
Cloning into 'dare-rare'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fmenol/dare-rare/': SSL connection timeout
If I use GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
the last message I get is
== Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
For reference:
!pip install
works fine, but commands like "sudo apt update" or "sudo apt upgrade" are also stuck at retrieving headers.
Any hint at what might be happening would super appreciated!
